# Bootstrap Vertical align two columns that are offset

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have code that looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 vmiddle">
 test<br>test
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-4 vmiddle">
  test2
 </div>
</div>
```

Notice the first column is offset by 4.  I want to vertically align these columns, so my css:

```
.vmiddle{
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:middle;
 float:none;
}
```

But what happens is the second column gets displaced to the next row.  I think it has something to do with the `float:none` but can't figure out why.  Can anyone help?

Please see this bootply for what this looks like: http://www.bootply.com/1emdJSmlgl

Thank you!

Comment: yes bootstrap uses float to put the 2 col divs next to eachother. and if you disable float they will be below eachother

Comment: if you want a solution, you need to make both boxes equal height and use something like `display:  table-cell` and vertical align to make the contents vertically alignt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove space between to `inline-block` div like following way:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 vmiddle">
    test<br>test
  </div><!--
  --><div class="col-xs-4 vmiddle">
    test2
  </div>
```

**[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/7o12kMCueP)**

Comment: Thanks! Could you kindly explain why this resolves the issue?

Comment: @pauliwago check this article. https://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block `display:inline-block` display white-space visually which is between div. To remove it use this.

Answer (score 0):

with bootstrap 4 you can use

`align-self-center`

for example

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col align-self-start">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col align-self-center">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col align-self-end">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```